# where can I find the code for grid Action buttons in acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I would like to see the code behind the grid actions button. let say buttons in the grid sectoin of  Bills and Adjustment Screen are marked with orange boxes.

I would like to see how the code is configured behind the buttons.
Where can I find the file or code in the Acumatica website folder?

**Especially I want code behind the "ADD SUBCONTRACT" button.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for the buttons/actions looks like it comes from the construction edition found in PX.Objects.CN.Subcontracts.AP.GraphExtensions.ApInvoiceEntryAddSubcontractsExtension (PX.Objects.CN.dll)

Snippets of related code:

```
[PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Add Subcontracts", FieldClass = "DISTR", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    public virtual IEnumerable addSubcontracts(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
      this.Base.checkTaxCalcMode();
      if (!this.ShouldAddSubcontracts())
        return adapter.Get();
      this.Base.updateTaxCalcMode();
      return this.addSubcontract(adapter);
    }

[PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Add Subcontract", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select, Visible = false)]
    public virtual IEnumerable addSubcontract(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
      return ApInvoiceEntryAddSubcontractsExtension.AddLines(new Func<PXAdapter, IEnumerable>(this.Base1.AddPOOrder2), adapter);
    }

    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Add Subcontract Line", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    public virtual IEnumerable addSubcontractLines(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
      this.Base.checkTaxCalcMode();
      return this.ShouldAddSubcontractLines() ? this.addSubcontractLine(adapter) : adapter.Get();
    }

    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Add Subcontract Line", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select, Visible = false)]
    public virtual IEnumerable addSubcontractLine(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
      return ApInvoiceEntryAddSubcontractsExtension.AddLines(new Func<PXAdapter, IEnumerable>(this.Base2.AddPOOrderLine2), adapter);
    }

    private static IEnumerable AddLines(
      Func<PXAdapter, IEnumerable> addLine,
      PXAdapter adapter)
    {
      try
      {
        return addLine(adapter);
      }
      catch (PXException ex) when (ex.MessageNoPrefix == "Failed to add one or more lines from the PO order. Please check the Trace for details.")
      {
        throw new Exception("SC Error: Failed to add one or more lines from the Subcontract. Please check the Trace for details.");
      }
    }
```

Looking at this code we can see it will use AddPOOrder2 from PX.Objects.PO.GraphExtensions.APInvoiceSmartPanel.AddPOOrderExtension from PX.Objects.dll

This code is found in the source availabine in Acumatica as:

```
[PXUIField(DisplayName = Messages.AddPOOrder, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select, Visible = false)]
        [PXLookupButton]
        [APMigrationModeDependentActionRestriction(
            restrictInMigrationMode: true,
            restrictForRegularDocumentInMigrationMode: true,
            restrictForUnreleasedMigratedDocumentInNormalMode: true)]
        public virtual IEnumerable AddPOOrder2(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            bool isInvoice = (Base.Document.Current.DocType == APDocType.Invoice),
                isPrepayment = (Base.Document.Current.DocType == APDocType.Prepayment);
            if (Base.Document.Current != null &&
                isInvoice &&
                Base.Document.Current.Released == false &&
                Base.Document.Current.Prebooked == false)
            {
                List<POOrder> orders = poorderslist.Cache.Updated.RowCast<POOrder>().Where(rc => rc.Selected == true).ToList();
                foreach (POOrder rc in orders)
                {
                    Base.InvoicePOOrder(rc, false);
                }
                Base.AttachPrepayment(orders);
            }
            return adapter.Get();
        }
```

The Base call here is referring to `APInvoiceEntry`

Answer (score 0):

when you decompile the PX.Objects.dll file we can find code for **"ADD PO"**

> PX.Objects.PO.GraphExtensions.APInvoiceSmartPanel.AddPOOrderExtension

but, I need code for **ADD Subcontracts**